# Vlookup with multiple conditions in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

so I have the following data: where column A has the date and Column B has the monthly budget, but column A is a pull data from supermetrics so there are lots of missing dates.
then I create a new column like in column D where all the dates are there and column E is the Budget per daily. I use a formula like the following:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IFERROR(
  B3:B/
  VLOOKUP(
   TEXT(
    IFERROR(
     IF(DAY(A3:A)=1,A3:A,""),
     D3:D
    ),
    "MMMM"
   ),
   {
    TEXT(
     IFERROR(
      IF(DAY(A3:A)=1,A3:A,""),
      D3:D
     ),
     "MMMM"
    ),
    DAY(EOMONTH(D3:D,0))
   },
   2,
   FALSE
  ),
  1
 )
)
```

But with this formula I still get a value of 0 as a result of column A having missing date data, how do I overcome this from the formula I made late without adding a new column

the conclusion from the formula is to look at the budget from column A which matches column D by pulling the name of the month because each case does not necessarily have the same budget every month. and dividing the budget based on the number of dates in that month

[image]
[image]

Comment: Working with dates can be tricky. You can be easier helped if you were to share a test sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this formula: it Filters column B according to the match of month and year, and with INDEX returns first value. That value is divided by the days of the last day of the month. Try it and let me know!

```
=BYROW(D3:D,LAMBDA(d,IF(d="","",INDEX(FILTER(B:B,MONTH(A:A)=MONTH(d),YEAR(A:A)=YEAR(d)),1)/DAY(EOMONTH(d,0)))))
```

Comment: You could use MAP instead of BYROW to add more variables in adjacent cells. I don't get exactly your expected result, but try: `=MAP(E5:E,F5:F,LAMBDA(E,F,IF(F=0,0,IF(E="","",INDEX(FILTER(D5:D,MONTH(E5:E)=MONTH(E),YEAR(A5:A)=YEAR(E)),1)/DAY(EOMONTH(E,0))))))`